# Convert range input to int or Format to return dollar

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, format

I've got a simple range field that I am using to return a Return on Investment (ROI). I am displaying the return figure as currency but would like to also display the investment size (input) as a currency also. This is the basic JS without my attempts of displaying the value as currency:

```js
function formatDollar(num) {
  var p = num.toFixed(2).split(".");
  return "$" + p[0].split("").reverse().reduce(function(acc, num, i, orig) {
    return num == "-" ? acc : num + (i && !(i % 3) ? "," : "") + acc;
  }, "") + "." + p[1];
}


function investSize(val) {
  price = val * 0.21;
  price = formatDollar(price);
  document.getElementById('investing').value = 'Investment Size $' + val;
  document.getElementById('roi').innerHTML = price;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="range" min="25000" max="900000" value="0" step="5000" oninput="investSize(this.value);" id="input" />
  <div style="width:350px;">
    <div class="arrow-up"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="invNumber"><output id="investing">Ivestment Size $25,000</output></div>
  <p class="return-text">RETURN AT 21%</p>
  <h3 id="roi">$5,250.00</h3>
</form>
```

Any advice as to how to accomplish this? I'm not having luck using the existing formatDollar function to convert.

Thanks.

Comment: well you are not calling it so.....

Comment: @epascarello, I know this. 
I tried a few things when calling it and was not getting the result I wanted.
Any advice on how it should be called, or what is needed before calling it, with relation to the context of the investment amount? that is the part that the question is relating to.

Comment: Not sure what your issue with calling the function is. formatDollar(val)

Comment: This is my attempt at that. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxzyXV?editors=1011

Comment: well your code on the codepen is not the same as the code above. The code above works fine for me... And if you alter the line `'Investment Size $' + val;` to be `'Investment Size ' + formatDollar(val);`, it formats it too....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had another code pen that I was fiddling with, obviously updated the wrong one, sorry.
The above works fine, but does not format to dollar. When I add your suggested line of  'Investment Size ' + formatDollar(val); the range slider no longer updates, it stays as the place holder text in the HTML.